# Installing Thunderbird 3.1 on Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty)

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu-9.04, thunderbird

I tried the instructions here:

[How to install Thunderbird 3 in Ubuntu 9.10/9.04/8.10/8.04](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-thunderbird-3-in-ubuntu-9-109-048-108-04.html)

but when I type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net jaunty Release:
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
NO_PUBKEY EF4186FE247510BE
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I downloaded the tarball [here](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/thunderbird/download/?product=thunderbird-3.1.7&os=linux&lang=en-US) and it doesn't run (says "File not found" when I try to run thunderbird or thunderbird-bin). The README.txt is useless as it just points back to the useless [Release notes](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/3.1.7/releasenotes).

I'm running GNOME, no strange window managers or anything.

#### For want of a nail

By the way, are there any Linux mail clients that can simply auto-populate the To: field with the contacts from an LDAP/CardDAV server (Zimbra hosted at mail.01.com) when I compose an email? That's all I really want.

Answer (score 0):

```
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Have you tried this already? If not give that a shot first.

If the issue persists, try a different repository list. Open up `/etc/apt/sources.list`, comment out your current repositories just in case, then paste in the following:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

Comment: OK after changing the source list apt-get update works but when I do sudo apt-get install thunderbird-3.1 thunderbird-3.1-gnome-support it says couldn't find package

Comment: Ok just looked at that article it's about a year old. I believe Thunderbird is on revision 3.1.7 now, but 9.04 wouldn't have builds for that yet I imagine. Try an apt-get update then check synaptic package manager for Thunderbird.

Comment: no luck ... just Thunderbird 2.x